# Load table with many records as collection

Tags: nhibernate, sql-server-ce, fluent

What is the best way to load table with many records (10 millions).

Currently, I do the following:

```
Session.QueryOver<Table>().List();
```

And I get the following Exception:

```
     threw exception: 
NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not execute query
[ SELECT this_.Id as Id7_0_, this_.Tag as Tag7_0_, this_.Vss as Vss7_0_, this_.checkpoint_id as checkpoint4_7_0_, this_.vpg_id as vpg5_7_0_ FROM "CheckpointToProtectionGroup" this_ ]
[SQL: SELECT this_.Id as Id7_0_, this_.Tag as Tag7_0_, this_.Vss as Vss7_0_, this_.checkpoint_id as checkpoint4_7_0_, this_.vpg_id as vpg5_7_0_ FROM "CheckpointToProtectionGroup" this_] ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
```

Comment: You shouldn't. And best for what?

Comment: Best for not getting the outOfMemopryException Exception. Should I load it in parts? how to do it ?

Comment: Limit the resultset by using a where clause.  You'll never need to work on all the records.

Comment: @Frederik you are right but that's an application request! We need it when the application is starting-up. Is there a way loading all data from a table using few iterations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip/Take or SetFirstResult/SetMaxResults to load in batches. You must also clear the session between each batch. And/or use stateless session. And/or let the query itself project to a simple DTO instance which NHibernate won't track to reduce memory consumption. Or not use NHibernate for such bulk loading (it is not the primary use case for NHibernate).

Comment: QueryOver<...>().Skip(n).Take(m).